# Form content not visible on django homepage?

Tags: django

I was trying my hands on learning django and tried creating a resume builder project where user can get form based template by entering some details on the form, but the form is not visible on the homepage. I'm attaching template code for more refrence. I can only see submit button on the homepage

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
    {{form.as_p}}
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Person,Experiences,EducationDetails,Academics,Skills,AreaOfInterest

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Person
        fields=('first_name','last_name','gender','email','contact_no','website','github','linkedin')
        widgets={
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'title':'First Name'}),
        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'title':'Last Name'}),
        'gender': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'title':'Gender'}),
        'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'title':'Email'}),
        'github': forms.URLInput(attrs={'title':'Github'}),
        'linkedin': forms.URLInput(attrs={'title':'Linkedin'}),
        'website': forms.URLInput(attrs={'title':'Website'})
        }
class ExperienceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Experiences
        fields = ('work_choice','title','start_duration','end_duration','description')
        widgets = {
        'work_choices' : forms.Select(attrs={'title':'WorkChoice'}),
        'title' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'title':'Title'}),
        'start_duration' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'title':'Start duration'}),
        'End_duration' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'title':'End duration'}),
        'description' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'title':'Description'})
        }
class EducationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EducationDetails
        fields = ('degree_choice','stream','passing_year','gpa')
        widgets = {
        'degree_choice' : forms.Select(attrs={'title':'Degree'}),
        'stream' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'title':'Stream'}),
        'passing_year' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'title':'Passing Year'}),
        'gpa' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'title':'GPA'})
        }

class SkillsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Skills
        fields = ('skills_description',)
        widgets = {
            'skills_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'title': 'Professional Skills'})
        }


class AcademicsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Academics
        fields = ('academics_description',)
        widgets = {

            'academics_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'title': 'Academics'})
        }


class AreaOfInterestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AreaOfInterest
        fields = ('area_of_interest_detail',)
        widgets = {

            'area_of_interest_detail': forms.Textarea(attrs={'title': 'Area Of Interest'})
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
#from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.sites.requests import RequestSite

from .forms import PersonForm,ExperienceForm,AcademicsForm,AreaOfInterestForm,EducationForm,SkillsForm
from .models import Person,Experiences,EducationDetails,Academics,Skills,AreaOfInterest


def resumeFill(request):
    template_name = 'resumefill.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        personform = PersonForm(data=request.POST)
        educationform = EducationForm(data=request.POST)
        experienceform = ExperienceForm(data=request.POST)
        academicsform = AcademicsForm(data=request.POST)
        areaOfInterestform = AreaOfInterestForm(data=request.POST)
        skillsform = SkillsForm(data=request.POST)
        
        if personform.is_valid():
            perform.save()
            
        if educationform.is_valid():
            educationform.save()
        
        if experienceform.is_valid():
            experienceform.save()
            
        if academicsform.is_valid():
            academicsform.save()
            
        if areaOfInterestform.is_valid():
            areaOfInterestform.save()
        
        if skillsform.is_valid():
            skillsform.save()
        
    return render(request,template_name,{'personform':PersonForm(),'educationform':EducationForm(),'experienceform':ExperienceForm(),'academicsform':AcademicsForm(),'areaOfInterestform':AreaOfInterestForm(),'skillsform':SkillsForm(),})
     
def resumeView(request):
    template_name = 'resume_view.html'
    site_name = RequestSite(request).domain
    person = Person.objects.all()
    experience = Experiences.objects.all()
    education = EducationDetails.objects.all()
    academics = Academics.objects.all()
    skills = Skills.objects.all()
    areaOfInterest = AreaOfInterest.objects.all()
    return render(request,template_name,{'site_name':site_name,'person':person,'experience':experience,'education':education,'academics':academics,'skills':skills,'areaOfInterest':areaOfInterest,})
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
# Create your models here.




class Person(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('M','Male'),
    ('F','Female'),
    ('Others', 'Trans')) 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES,max_length=10)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    contact_no = models.CharField(unique=True,null=False,max_length=13)
    website = models.URLField()
    github = models.URLField()
    linkedin = models.URLField()
    
    def full_name(self):
        return " ".join([self.first_name+self.last_name])
class Experiences(models.Model):
    WORK_CHOICES = (
    ('I','Internship'),
    ('FTE','Full Time Employee'),
    ('Free','Freelancer'))
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_choice = models.CharField(choices=WORK_CHOICES,max_length=20)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_duration = models.DateField() 
    end_duration = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField()

class EducationDetails(models.Model):
    DEGREE_CHOICES = (('XII','High School'),
    ('B.Tech/B.E./BCA/B.Com','Bachelors'),
    ('M.Tech/MCA/M.Com','Masters'))
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    degree_choice = models.CharField(choices=DEGREE_CHOICES, max_length=300)
    stream = models.TextField(max_length=200,null=True)
    passing_year = models.DateField()
    gpa = models.IntegerField()
    
class Academics(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    academics_description = models.TextField()  
    
class Skills(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skills_description = models.TextField()

class AreaOfInterest(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area_of_interest_detail = models.TextField()
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^resumefill',views.resumeFill,name='resumefill'),
url(r'^resumeview',views.resumeView,name='resumeview'),
]
```

urls.py of project structure

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'',include('portfolio.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Can you include the function code?

Comment: Please include you `views.py` `urls.py` `forms.py` and `models.py` code

Comment: @AnandaBayuPutraYudhistira including views.py urls.py forms.py and models.py

Comment: @sunilghimire hope this helps if there is any other file required let me know

Comment: @AnandaBayuPutraYudhistira i have attached forms.py views.py urls.py and models.py

Comment: @Manthanjain you don't pass the 'form' variable to your template, instead, you can use {{personform.as_p}} or {{educationform.as_p}} etc. make sure the variable you use on the template is the same with the variable you pass from 'return render' on your views.py

Comment: @AnandaBayuPutraYudhistira thank you so much this solves my issue. Thank you for solving it so quickly.

Comment: @Manthanjain you are welcome, don't forget to vote up and marked as answered so others can use this as a reference too.

Comment: @AnandaBayuPutraYudhistira sure i'll do  that, thanks for the reminder

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you don't pass the `form` variable to your template, instead, you can use `{{personform.as_p}}` or `{{educationform.as_p}}` etc..

Make sure the variable you use on the template is the same with the variable you pass from 'return render' on your views.py